# How to create unique value field in Intramaps Roam for

Tags: intramaps-roam

Is there a way to create a field (eg. text widget) that only accepts unique values (eg. feature_ID).

May be by adding some python logic, checking if the entered value already exists in the attribute table of the layer...

For instance, if I have a "feature_ID" text widget in my form, it shouldn't be possible to

Any ideas?